# Bad quality of circle stroke with gradient

Tags: swiftui, stroke

```
 Circle()
    .trim(from: viewModel.lenghts[index].from, to: viewModel.lenghts[index].to)
    .stroke(someGradient, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
```

Tried set a gradient in .stroke initializer, tried to use .fill(Gradient..)
And my circle stroke looks pixelated. When use just a color (foregraundColor(Color..) all is ok. `My gradient: AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [CustomColors.red, CustomColors.pink]), center: .center, angle: .degrees(270))`

What am I doing wrong? Tried linear, angular gradients

[image: pixelated stroke]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've zoomed in. Try a bigger shape for better quality.

Compare these two visually identical rings and see the difference of zooming **in** and **out**:

#### High Quality

This one zoomed **out** to match the size that you are seeing.

[image: High quality]

#### Low Quality

This one zoomed **in** to match the size that you are seeing.

[image: Low quality]

You can see the difference even in the text.

---

Full Demo code:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Low quality")
                .font(.system(size: 8))

            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.1, to: 0.9)
                .stroke(g, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .padding(8)
        }

        ZStack {
            Text("Hight quality")
                .font(.system(size: 50))

            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.1, to: 0.9)
                .stroke(g, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 60, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
                .padding(50)
        }
    }
```

---

**Note** that you can use `.scaleEffect` modifier to scale it with code (if you really need to)

Comment: Done it with `.scaleEffect(0.3)` and equivalently increased circle frame size and now it looks perfectly, thank you